# Executing a shell with a command and returning

Tags: bash

`man bash` seems to suggest that if I want to execute a command in a separate `bash` shell all I have to do is `bash -c command`:

```
   -c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.
```

I want to do that because I need to run a few things in different environments:

```
bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc.a -c mytest.a
bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc.b -c mytest.b
```

However, that didn't work as expected; one can see that by the number of `bash` shells running, for example:

```
$ bash
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7554 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 7573 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
28616 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
$ exit
exit
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7582 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
28616 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
$ bash -c ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7583 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
28616 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
```

How should the invocation of `bash` should be modified so that it would start a new shell with the specified rc, execute the given command in that shell (with the env modified according to the rc), and exit back?

Answer (score 2):

It's already working exactly the way you want it to. The lack of an extra process is simply due to bash's tail-call optimization.

Bash recognizes that there's no point in having a shell instance whose only job is to wait for a process and exit. It will instead skip the fork and `exec` the process directly. This is a huge win for e.g. `var=$(ps)`, where it cuts the number of expensive forks from 2 to 1.

If you give it additional commands to run afterwards, this optimization is no longer valid, and then you'll see the additional process:

```
$ bash -c 'ps'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4531 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
 4540 pts/10   00:00:00 ps

$ bash -c 'ps; exit $?'
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 4531 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
 4549 pts/10   00:00:00 bash
 4550 pts/10   00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc.a mytest.a` will already run `mytest.a` in a separate process. `-c` is for specifying a shell command *directly*, rather than running a script.

```
# NO!
bash for x in 1 2 3; do echo "$x"; done

# Yes.
bash -c 'for x in 1 2 3; do echo "$x"; done'
```